# Extract all lines between almost the same string in python excluding the last if it contains a different string

Tags: python

I need to extract all the lines between each 'Fetching' string or EOF, including the first 'Fetching', check if it contains `40500000` and write it to '405' file or else write it a 'Not'. Note there could potentially be hundreds of thousands (or more) of these 'Fetching' strings. My text file excerpt as follows:

```
Fetching: 0000007442476828
gzip: Archive/*2023-09-18*.gz: No such file or directory
gzip: Archive/*2023-09-18*.gz: No such file or directory
gzip: Archive/*2023-09-18*.gz: No such file or directory
gzip: Archive/*2023-09-18*.gz: No such file or directory
gzip: Archive/*2023-09-18*.gz: No such file or directory
gzip: Archive/*2023-09-18*.gz: No such file or directory
gzip: Archive/*2023-09-18*.gz: No such file or directory
gzip: Archive/*2023-09-18*.gz: No such file or directory
gzip: Archive/*2023-09-18*.gz: No such file or directory
Fetching: 0000007442477158
0000007442477158|40320|4000|1|0||0|||12345679
Fetching: 0000007442477234
0000007442477234|40320|4000|1|0||0|||40500000
Fetching: 0000007442477223
Fetching: 0000007442477333
0000007442477333|500000|4001|1|0||0|||40500000
0000007442477333|40320|4000|1|0||0|||40500000
0000007442477333|12345|3000|1|0||0|||40500000
Fetching: 0000007442477999
<EOF>
```

My 'Not' file would look like this:

```
Fetching: 0000007442476828
gzip: Archive/*2023-09-18*.gz: No such file or directory
gzip: Archive/*2023-09-18*.gz: No such file or directory
gzip: Archive/*2023-09-18*.gz: No such file or directory
gzip: Archive/*2023-09-18*.gz: No such file or directory
gzip: Archive/*2023-09-18*.gz: No such file or directory
gzip: Archive/*2023-09-18*.gz: No such file or directory
gzip: Archive/*2023-09-18*.gz: No such file or directory
gzip: Archive/*2023-09-18*.gz: No such file or directory
gzip: Archive/*2023-09-18*.gz: No such file or directory
Fetching: 0000007442477158
0000007442477158|40320|4000|1|0||0|||12345679
Fetching: 0000007442477234
Fetching: 0000007442477223
Fetching: 0000007442477999
```

And my '405' file would then look like this

```
Fetching: 0000007442477234
0000007442477234|40320|4000|1|0||0|||40500000
Fetching: 0000007442477333
0000007442477333|500000|4001|1|0||0|||40500000
0000007442477333|40320|4000|1|0||0|||40500000
0000007442477333|12345|3000|1|0||0|||40500000
```

Everything I'm reading up on, seems to be about a `<start>` and `<end>` string. As you can imagine I have no idea what my `end` string would be other than what it starts with and I have no idea on the amount of entries between each `Fetching`. I'm still in the infancies of the code an i'm already stuck just printing the lines between the two Fetching:

```
a = []
with open("FileName") as file:
    for i in file.readlines():
        a.append(i)
for j in a:
    c=2
    while c!=0:
        if 'Fetching:' in j:
            c=c-1
        print(j)
    break
```

It honestly looks like my approach is all wrong

Comment: Have you considered using `regex` ?

Comment: Shouldn't the line `Fetching: 0000007442477234` be in `Not` instead of `405`? As I understood it a fetch mitght consist of multible lines (each line with `Fetching:` marks the start of a new one) and if `40500000` matches any line of a fetch the whole fetch it is assigned to `405`, else `Not`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, a fetch can consist of multiple lines. To check a whole fetch and not only single line I would first read the file into a list of fetches by adding a new element whenever `Fetching:` is the first part of a line and adding all other lines to the last fetch. Break the loop when the line is `<EOF>`.

Then check each fetch (consisting of all the respective lines) to contain `40500000` and split the fetches list accodingly into two strings:

```py
def split_file(file_path):
    fetching = []
    four_o_five = ''
    not_four_o_five = ''
    # Create List of fetches
    with open(file_path) as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            if line.split()[0] == 'Fetching:':
                fetching.append(line)  # add new fetch string
            elif line == '<EOF>':
                break
            else:
                fetching[-1] += line  # add line to last appended fetch string
    # Sort fetches to the respective lists (later files)
    for fetch in fetching:
        if '40500000' in fetch:
            four_o_five += fetch
        else:
            not_four_o_five += fetch
    return four_o_five, not_four_o_five


if __name__ == "__main__":
    fof, nfof = split_file('data.txt')
    print(fof)
    print(nfof)
```

Comment: At first glance your `fnof` is working like a charm :) but your `fof` albiet working is weirdly adding `gzip: Archive/*2023-09-18*.gz: No such file or directory` at the end of the block (before the next fetch)... Why?
I'll keep checking this file, since it's the important one but so far I dont mind that. Thanks

Comment: weird, it did not do this on my machine. Did it do so while using only your provided excerpt or your whole file? Maby in your file there is a fetch with both a line of `450` and the `gzip` error within it?

Comment: Yes Jan, you're right there is :) this makes sense now :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using generators or coroutines (not the asyncronous ones), so you avoid loading up all file in memory but only process line-by-line.

Here you have an example:

```py
def yield_line(path):
    """Generator that yields one line at a time."""
    with open(path) as f:
        while True:
            line = f.readline()
            if line:
                yield line
            else:
                break

for line in yield_line("filename.txt"):
    if "40500000" in line or "Fetching" in line:
        with open("yes.txt", mode="a") as f:
            f.writeline(lines_1)
    if "40500000" not in line or "Fetching" in line:
        with open("no.txt", mode="a") as f:
            f.writeline(lines_1)
```

Comment: Looks great, never seen something like this! One question though: wouldn't a line like `Fetching: 0000007442477999` getting added to `yes.txt` since it contains `Fetching` and therefore the `or` is fullfilled?

Comment: Hmm, after closer inspection of the data I cant say this is working - it seems the no file is containing those long digits that are in the yes file. Then I see entries in the yes file that aren't meant to be there either

Comment: I admit this is not giving the answer that @imp was looking for, it still needs some work. The approach though is what matters. Use generators!